# Why isn't my class working in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I was testing my code in IRB and I typed in this:

```
class be
  def new_text
    text = gets()
  end
  def show_text
    puts "#{text}"
  end
end
```

When I typed in new_text it worked but when I typed in show_text it came up with an error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `text' for #<BE:0xd3cc08>
        from (irb):14:in `show'
        from (irb):14:in `show'
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby1.9.2/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas of how to fix that?

Comment: use `CamelCase` for class names

Comment: it won't even compile if you don't use `CamelCase`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change text to be an instance variable:

```
class Be
  def new_text
    @text = gets()
  end
  def show_text
    puts "#{@text}"
  end
end
```

You're getting the error because the `show_text` method is trying to access a variable called `@text` which hadn't been defined in your original example.